# Maintaining a clone of a git repository

Tags: git, clone, fossil

I want to make a clone of a github repostitory in a (self-hosted) bitbucket server and from time to time pull the latest changes from the github repository.  In our clone we're going to do some experimental stuff which will never leave our repository.

To illustrate; with fossil I'd make sure that our repository and their repository has the same project id, and I'd do this:

```
$ cd ~/checkout/prjdir
$ fossil pull https://their.org/prj/foo --once
```

This would get all the latest checkins, branches, tags, etc.  And then to push it to our organization's server:

```
$ fossil push
```

There will never be any conflicts; our changes will be made on experimental branches so there's no need for any merges when updating from upstream.

I've tried to replicate the fossil workflow and copy/pasted some things which seem relevant and come up with this for the initial cloning:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git
$ cd bar
$ git remote set-url origin https://ourbitbucket.org/foo/bar.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

This however doesn't appear to have brought with it the tags (tags are important to us).

With git (github as upstream and our bitbucket server for our own tags/branches):

1. how do I make a complete clone of a repository (including all
   branches and tags)?
2. once I have a cloned repository, how do I
   pull all the latest changes (branches, tags included) from upstream
   (on github) and push them to our server (bitbucket)?

Comment: How do you know the tags weren't cloned? Or you wanted to `push --tags`?

Comment: Would this simply be fixed by doing `git fetch --tags` ?

Comment: @choroba Seems like "--tags" was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't change the URL of the repository. Just create two remotes, `upstream` and `origin`.

Tags aren't pushed by default. Use `--tags` to push them.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git
$ cd bar
$ git remote rename origin upstream
$ git remote add origin https://ourbitbucket.org/foo/bar.git
$ git push -u --tags origin master
```

Whenever you want to synchronize with the upstream, do

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull upstream master
```

or even

```
$ git reset --hard upstream/master
```

and rebase your branch (or merge master into it) to incorporate their changes into your work:

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git rebase master
```

or

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git merge master
```

Comment: So after the initial clone, I'd use "git pull upstream" followed by "git push -u --tags origin master"? Care to expand the answer with a post-initial clone workflow example?

Comment: @cypheratheist: `clone` already pulls, so no need to pull upstream after clone.